# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'SequenceClassifierOutput' and 'int'

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I am using hugginface library to train a bert model on classification problem.

```
    model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=10) 

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
       sequence, label = batch
       input_ids, attention_mask, labels = self.prepare_batch(sequence=sequence, label=label)
       loss = self.model(input_ids=input_ids,
                      attention_mask=attention_mask,
                      labels=labels) 
       tensorboard_logs = {'train_loss': loss}
```

I am getting the following error just before the training starts:

```
in training_step
closure_loss = closure_loss / self.trainer.accumulate_grad_batches 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'SequenceClassifierOutput' and 'int'
```

I am using pytorch-lightning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling self.model() returns an object of type *SequenceClassifierOutput*.
To access the loss you need to call it's loss attribute:
Replace

```
loss = self.model(input_ids=input_ids,
                      attention_mask=attention_mask,
                      labels=labels)
```

by

```
output = self.model(input_ids=input_ids,
                      attention_mask=attention_mask,
                      labels=labels) 
loss = output.loss
```